# RAMP UP in Thread Group of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have issue with setting ramp-up in jmeter.

My test scenario described below.

There are 3 thread groups:

```
Thread Group1 - 2 Users - Ramp up 10
Thread Group2 - 3 users - Ramp up 15
Thread Group3 - 5 users - Ramp up 25
```

Problem i'm facing with above scenario is the following.

First user of all the thread groups is kicked off at a same time.
But i don't want like that, i want the following:

- In first 10 seconds, 2 users of first thread group should kick off.
- After 10 seconds to the test, thread group 2 should kick off their users.
- After 25 seconds to the test, third group should kick off their users.

I have seen one option in Jmeter that "Run thread groups consecutively" but if i set that thread group 2 will never start until thread group1 users should complete their requests execution.

Answer (score 4):

[jMeter Plugins'](http://jmeter-plugins.org) [Ultimate thread group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) and [Stepping thread group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) give you far more control over threads.

Answer (score 1):

Add a startup delay to second and third thread group:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group

This should do the job.

You can put anything in Start Time and End Time as these will be overriden by startup delay and duration.

Also note:

```
    Start Time  If the scheduler checkbox is selected, one can choose an absolute 
    start time. When you start your test, JMeter will wait until the specified start time 
    to begin testing. Note : The Startup Delay field over-rides this - see below.
```

Note particularly:

**Note: the Startup Delay field over-rides this - see below.**

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I cannot add start Up delay since schedular expects start time and end time. I cannot enter start time as my test has 10 thread groups. Is there any other solution for the same?

Comment: Read documentation carefully, I updated my answer. My method works.