# How to implement ramp-up scenario with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to implement the following scenario in Jmeter by ramping up users gradually.
How can I achieve that?

Thread group A:

- Every minute, 10 thread should ramp up,
- unless they reach the total max of 500 threads,
- and then they all should run for 4 hours continually.

My goal is to check the average response time for 4 hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RAMP UP in Thread Group of Jmeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723678/ramp-up-in-thread-group-of-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SteppingThreadGroup plugin -> http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/ instead of common ThreadGroup.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways are available

1. Threadgroup - inbuilt

   [image]

Total duration is 14400 seconds i.e. 4hrs (This includes rampup, generally rampup should be excluded from test duration then you should set test duration = 14400 + 3000)

2. Stepping threadgroup from jmeter plugins

[image]

This can also be used in same way
keep rampup duration and total duration difference in consideration